# Report Viewer DLLS Problemas

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

Tengo un error tratando de ver un reporte en una aplicación ***ASP.Net***, el proyecto ya está compilado y publicado en un servidor.

Tengo todas las *DLL* necesarias en el **Bin** de mi carpeta, y también en el **web.config**.

Error:

> Compilation Error (Error de compilación)
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Descripción (en español): Se produjo un error durante la compilación de un recurso necesario para atender esta solicitud. Revise los siguientes detalles de error específicos y modifique el código fuente de forma adecuada.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type  *"Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer"* exist in both (El tipo *ReportViewer* existe en ambos archivos):
>
> *C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms/9.0.0.0__B03F5F7F11D50A3A/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll*
>
> *C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms/11.0.0.0__89845DCD8080CC91/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll*
>
> Source Error (Error de origen):
>
> Línea 12: `<div>` 
> Línea 13: `<asp:ScriptManager ID="script1" runat="server" >EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>` 
> **Línea 14:         `<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptDetalles" runat="Server">`** 
> Línea 15:             `<LocalReport ReportPath="rptauditoriaDetalles.rdlc"></LocalReport>` 
> Línea 16:         `</rsweb:ReportViewer>`

Comment: es un conflicto de nombres, debido a que tienes dos versiones del mismo módulo en cuestión.  debes corregir el web config 

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4b643287-c495-4ce2-8a82-fd9f7a578f6e/ayuda-error-errorreportviewer-is-ambiguous-in-the-namespace-microsoftreportingwebforms?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: ya lo hize pero aun asi no funciona

Comment: Esto lleva mucho tiempo parado, pero estoy convencido de que tiene una fácil solución. Podrías pegarnos la configuración relevante de tu `web.config` para que podamos pegarle un repaso?

Answer (score 0):

A mi me sucedió algo parecido, la causa del problema es que trabajas con distinta dlls, la de tu pc(localhost) con la que tiene el servidor. Copia tu dll  Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll a la carpeta bin de tu proyecto, la referencias de ahí, despues en propiedades de la dll, le cambias el atributo de Copia Local a valor true, y ahí debería ser solucionado.